# Adding options programmatically to plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I had the following code:

```
 framework7.actions([
            // First buttons group
            [
                // Group Label
                {
                    text: 'Here comes some optional description or warning for actions below',
                    label: true
                },
                // First button
                {
                    text: 'Alert',
                    onClick: function () {
                        framework7.alert('He Hoou!');
                    }
                },
                // Another red button
                {
                    text: 'Nice Red Button ',
                    red: true,
                    onClick: function () {
                        framework7.alert('You have clicked red button!');
                    }
                },
            ],
            // Second group
            [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    bold: true
                }
            ]
        ]);
```

In the above instance, how would I only add the option/code for "First button" if a certain condition was true. eg (if (need_first_button) {} ). If the condition is false then we don't pass that button to the plugin.

And the same goes for "Another red button". How could I only include that option when ( if (need_red_button) {} ) was true?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the argument first, then modify it as needed, finally pass it to the framework function:

```
var params = [
            // First buttons group
            [
                // Group Label
                {
                    text: 'Here comes some optional description or warning for actions below',
                    label: true
                }
            ],
            // Second group
            [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    bold: true
                }
            ]
        ];

if(needFirstButton){
    params[0].push({
        text: 'Alert',
        onClick: function () {
            framework7.alert('He Hoou!');
        }        
    });
}

if(needRedButton){
        params[0].push({
        text: 'Nice Red Button ',
        red: true,
        onClick: function () {
            framework7.alert('You have clicked red button!');
        }       
    }); 
}

framework7.actions(params);
```

You can easily add new groups, just by pushing an array to `params` instead of `params[x]`

```
params.push([
        {
            text: 'New group button 1',
            red: true,
            onClick: function () {
                framework7.alert('You have clicked red button!');
            }       
        }
]);
```

The above adds a new group containing one button, but you could add more buttons to it by comma separating the objects.

Comment: params[0][0].push is not a function

Comment: Think it is meant to be params[0].push?

Comment: My mistake - yes it should be [0]. The `[0]` represents the first element in the params array, which itself is an array (containing the group label and buttons).

Comment: To add a button to the second group, do the same thing but use `params[1].push` instead.

Comment: Thanks, for your help.
Is it possible to programmatically add new group sections as well, to push into? eg params[3].push( at the moment will cause an error as there is no #3 group, so is it possible to programmatically add an empty group (2, or 3, or whatever is next in line)to push into?